# Tools to build a UI markup language parser

Tags: parsing, user-interface, yacc, markup, lex

For a school project, I need to implement a parser for a (probably XML-based) markup language for User Interfaces. Based on the input it generates a HTML document with various UI components (textareas, inputs, panels, dialogs etc.)

Do you have any suggestions for tools/libraries I might use for this? 
(At school we use Flex and Bison, but we're allowed to use modern tools -- maybe a tool that has the capabilities of both lex and yacc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is, as suggested, XML and your output is HTML, then that is the basic use case for XSLT. The *whole point* of XML is that you don't have to write your own parser, so if this was being done as a job of work rather than as a school project that would be the first technique to use. If you can't express it as a transformation, then you might look elsewhere.

If you don't want to use XML, then modern tools for plain-text languages include [parser expression grammars](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~baford/packrat/) and DSL synthesis tools such as [Microsoft M](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441702(v=MSDN.10).aspx).

PEGs free you from having to separately lex and parse, so a token can be context sensitive without complicating the grammar (as many tokens are in many languages), and some implementations mean you don't have to worry about left/right recursive loops.

DSL synthesis tools combine an IDE based grammar with a runtime semantics. Martin Fowler has a [book on DSLs on his site](http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/).

But for a UI definition language that is the input to a transformation, either XML or some other standard mapping of structure (JSON, YAML) which can act as the input to an XSLT processor via the SAX interface would be the first thing I would try.